# Moveit! and rviz interactive markers problem

Tags: ros, moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello dear Community!
Could someone help me with the problem I'm experiencing with Interactive Moveit! markers in rviz with my simple test robot arm.
Please review the link **[www.youtube.com/watch?v=M1c8A-DfghA](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M1c8A-DfghA)** and tell me please why I can't change the Goal State with the Interactive Marker? And as you would see from video I can do this through the Planning Tab, setting the random Goal State. What should I do to force Interactive Marker to change the Goal State?
Please help me with this stopper.

Please feel free to ask from me (I do really want find the problem) all that is necessary to help to resolve this problem. I have successfully used pr2_moveit_config tutorial, and Interactive Markers for move groups (like right_arm) out there works fine.

Thanks, Alexey!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/95626/moveit!-and-rviz-interactive-markers-problem/) by [maska](https://answers.ros.org/users/7951/maska/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2013-10-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is that having an arm with less than 6DOF, dont allow you to control your arm in position and orientation (since you dont have enough DOF to do that), so the motion planner fails. Then in this situation if you want to have a correct control you have to set an "only position planner".

---

Originally posted by [donmrsir](https://answers.ros.org/users/19553/donmrsir/) with karma: 363 on 2015-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To me it looks like the IK solver always fails to find a solution. Is your arm < 6DOF? Can you try to check the Approximate IK checkbox in the first tab?

---

Originally posted by [isucan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1805/isucan/) with karma: 1055 on 2013-10-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2